# Insert into certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using SQL Server 2005.

I have a table1 with  3 columns. And table2 with 4 columns.

I want to insert the records from table1 into table2.

But I dont want to insert into column1 from table2.

I want to start inserting from column2 on.

What can i do?
Thanks...

Comment: You could always look it up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I'm assuming `column1` is nullable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
insert into table2
(
    col2, col3, col4
)
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can combine select and insert in order to do this. This is how:

```
insert into table2 (col2, col3, col4)
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to use a `SELECT...FROM` in your `INSERT` to select the columns you want.

```
INSERT INTO table2
(
    column2, column3, column4
)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (column2,colum3,column4 )
SELECT  column1,column2,column3 FROM    Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
into into table2
(column2,......)
select column2 ..... from table1
```