# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. command.executeNonQuery(); help pleasse

Tags: c#, database

[image: image description here]

I got some problem on my button. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087410/insert-into-certain-columns)

Comment: Correct usage: `INSERT INTO [TableName] (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)`. If the column name contains spaces, wrap it inside square brackets, e.g. `[Column Name]` (NB: avoid using spaces as column name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The insert query you are executing is wrong, it should be

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (<COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ...>) VALUES (<VALUE1, VALUE2, ...>)
```

You just have written `VALUE` instead of `VALUES` and there is no comma between column names