# How to fix the error - Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

```
INSERT INTO Buy
SELECT Title
    ,Type1
    ,Tedat
    ,DATEADD(DAY, - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, Tarikh))
    ,Descrip
FROM Buy
WHERE (
    Tarikh BETWEEN 2019-03-21
    AND 2020-03-19
)
```

Comment: The documentation on [constants / literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) discusses how to write literals of all types. And stop the laziness. ALWAYS specify a column list in your insert statements. Do not create more work that needs to be done at a later date when the structure of the table is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your dates in quotes, as without them they are being evaluated as a series of integers, which isn't comparable with a date in your `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO Buy 
SELECT      Title,
            Type1,
            Tedat,
            DATEADD(DAY,-2,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,Tarikh)),
            Descrip 
FROM        Buy
WHERE       Tarikh BETWEEN '2019-03-21' AND '2020-03-19'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes on the date

```
 INSERT INTO Buy SELECT  Title,Type1,Tedat,DATEADD(DAY,-2,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,Tarikh)),Descrip FROM Buy
                                WHERE(Tarikh BETWEEN '2019-03-21' AND '2020-03-19' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the date in quotes, like `'2019-03-21'` instead of `2019 - 03 - 21`

```
INSERT INTO Buy
SELECT Title
    ,Type1
    ,Tedat
    ,DATEADD(DAY, -2, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, Tarikh))
    ,Descrip
FROM Buy
WHERE Tarikh BETWEEN '2019-03-21' AND '2020-03-19'
```

Besides, You ought to specify the column to avoid an unexpected error (insert into incorrect column or Just want to insert a number of columns instead of all)

```
INSERT INTO Buy(column1, column2,.. )
SELECT  Title, Tedat, .. 
FROM    Buy
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding

[Insert into certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087410/insert-into-certain-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Rozbeh